# Why isn't steam turbine condensation carried out in spare boilers?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, condensed-matter, electricity

Why do steam turbines at the power plants have to transfer heat to the environment or to so-called cooling towers? Why not reject the heat through tubes carrying the steam into another boiler (currently not in use)? Since the latter boiler's water will be at a higher temperature than ambient, it will take less energy to boil that water per gallon (when the boiler is used, of course)!

Please explain to me my misunderstandings. I don't believe that there is any violation of heat engine laws here, as the heat IS indeed lost and there is a temperature gradient!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boilers produce high temperature, high pressure steam to run through turbines.  Work is extracted from the steam to produce electricity, and the turbine exhaust is low temperature, low pressure steam.  Depending on the turbine, it's possible to place a water condenser immediately downstream of the turbine such that exhaust steam is condensed at vacuum conditions, meaning that the exhaust steam temperature may well be somewhat lower than one would expect.  Note that vacuum condensation ensures maximum pressure drop across the turbine, and hence, maximum work extracted from the steam.

Most boilers will work in a closed cycle, where exhaust steam is condensed and pumped back to the boilers.  There is always a bit of loss involved, so make-up water must be treated to ensure that it is not corrosive to piping.  Since there is make-up water, there will be a small amount of dissolved material entering the process, requiring the boiler to "blow down" a fraction of the water running through it to prevent dissolved solids buildup.  That blow-down water can indeed be used to preheat makeup water entering the boiler.

Now, to get more specific.  You asked "Why not reject the heat through tubes carrying the steam into another boiler (currently not in use)?".  A boiler that is not in use will be cold, so any heat rejected to it will ultimately be lost to the environment.  In addition, due to the phase change involved, the condensate will have the same temperature as the low pressure steam that produced it.  Transferring heat from this steam to boiler water requires a temperature difference, and a practical temperature difference in industry will be in the range of 10-20 deg F, so any water that you heat from the low pressure steam would be somewhat colder than the steam that heated it.  This means that it is more economical to condense the low pressure steam and send it directly to the boiler.

You also asked "Why do steam turbines at the power plants have to transfer heat to the environment or to so-called cooling towers?".  The boilers operate at a high temperature and high pressure.  It would take a LOT of work to compress low pressure steam back to a pressure that would send it back to the boiler to be heated.  The whole purpose of generating high pressure, high temperature steam is to extract work from it, so steam compression is a non-starter.  This means that low pressure steam must be condensed before sending it back to the boiler, because it is MUCH easier to pump water (incompressible) to a high pressure than it is to pump steam to a high pressure (large PV work required).  Due to this, the heat of vaporization of the low pressure steam must be rejected to the environment in order to condense it, and this is usually done in a cooling tower.

Answer (score -1):

I have read that some power plants do use the hot exhaust from the turbines in a second stage of generation.